# Higher voltage from comparator to lower voltage at the output... how?

Tags: voltage-divider

I am stuck on how to produce a lower voltage from an [opamp](https://www.analog.com/media/en/technical-documentation/data-sheets/14901afd.pdf) used as a comparator that swings from +15V to -15V to +5V at the output, and 0V (when it swings to -15V) as well.

I attached the circuit, but for the life of me, it seems so simple, yet I can't work it out.

[image]

Comment: What comparator are you using?

Comment: @PeterBennett LM1491

Comment: I can't find an LM1491 datasheet, but an LT1491 is a quad opamp, not a comparator.

Comment: @PeterBennett oh, sorry, I am using the LT1491 and yes, it is a quad opamp...

Comment: I see it is an LM1491 Stainless Steel Shaker Bottle 24oz. ;)

Comment: @TonyStewartEE75 lol :p

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The simple solution is to reduce the problem to a transfer function with Gain and Offset.

Input = -15 to + 15 V    , Diff=30V, mean = 0
Output = 0 to 5 V  , Diff = 5 V, mean = 2.5V

Thus the gain is 5 /30 and offset is + 2.5 V

[image]

30k//15k= 10k thus satisfies the offset of 2.5V
Then the divider load is 10k//15k = 6k so 6/(30+6) = 1/6 which = 5/30

But you can use KVL. I just did it in my head.

[image]

Comment: https://tinyurl.com/ybvk54kj